# Why Wordpress Unyson map has height 0?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a Google map on page in page builder using plugin for -Wordpress Unyson. But map has `height 0`. What have I done wrong?

[image: add map on page-builder]
[image: configuration location]
[image: configuration API key]
[image: height 0]
[image: height 0]
[image: no errors on console]

Comment: screenshots is here https://yadi.sk/i/T_kmZncv3TUhtR
https://yadi.sk/i/Bi6z98163TUhwH
https://yadi.sk/i/ZwnMGhdk3TUhxE
https://yadi.sk/i/MwLrPbtG3TUhyo
https://yadi.sk/i/GlDL3JEz3TUhzv
https://yadi.sk/i/17YgCspt3TUi2j

Comment: Hi Denis and welcome on StackOverflow! Maybe you should include your screenshots in the question (with the edit-function), so everyone can see it easily.

Comment: Moderator corrected my question, screenshots are visible now.